# DDOS interrupted by nmap?

Tags: nmap, ddos

I discovered one of my machines was under an ssh DDOS attack when I was looking at logs to find out why my disk was slow.  The auth log was about 90M, which is kind of unusual for this machine.

I ran an nmap against one of the IPs (nmap -P0 ).

Once I ran the nmap, the attack stopped from all the IPs.  Now there is just silence.

Has anyone seen this happen before?  If so, what was the cause?

N.B.  This machine is used for testing, and gets rebuilt a lot.  It's running Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Downvotes are not "derision". Please do not take them personally.

Comment: A question with a -1 almost never gets any attention, which means nobody is probably going to answer my question.  As a consequence, I will remain ignorant until I can find something other than this forum.  This isn't about taking it personally, it's about coming here looking for knowledge and getting basically told to pound sand.

Comment: None of what you've said is true ... which means that you are taking it personally.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a DDoS but a brute force attack. They had a monitor looking for their target (you) investigating them. Once you tried to scan them, they halted in order to avoid further analysis.

Comment: I had kind of guessed it was something like that.  Can you give any specifics?  Like what tool they may have been using, etc?

Comment: There are a thousand different tools

Comment: Can you name a tool that might have been used?

Comment: Why do you want the name of one of a possible thousand tools? If I know why you want to know, I can give you a more useful answer. Because all this is easily possible to script in Python, for instance.

Comment: This isn't my area.  I would like to learn more about what what the attacker might be doing/using, but I don't know where to start.  If there is a standard tool name, I could google that.  If there are named techniques, I could google those.  Basically I am looking for a hook into the field so I can learn more without spending hours unproductively wandering the internet.

Comment: Anything on the first page of results will get you started: https://www.google.com/search?q=distributed+ssh+brute+force+attacks

Comment: In addition to that, I had also googled "brute force ssh stops after nmap" and many variants of the words in my question.  I spent about an hour on it before I asked my question.  I am looking for something specific to what happened:  an attack was underway, and when I nmap'd them, they quit.

Comment: Perhaps there is something unclear in my question, which I am totally willing to own.  Perhaps a better way to phrase the question would be:  Name at least one botnet that can do a distributed brute force ssh attack, and halt the attack from all IPs when one of the IPs is nmap'd?

Comment: Its recommended by various agencies and security related groups to not ping, scan, nslookup, etc an attacker IP, because apparently this is common, where they will set up a firewall rule or something to monitor if an IP they dont control in the target's network starts scanning them. They know they've attracted too much attention. They could have a Linux box set up to run a script after an IPTables rule is matched, and have it all automated. And they could have one of the bots report this to the C2 server, which automatically pushes out a command to the bots to stop on that target.

Comment: @johndoe That is interesting.  If the goal is to stop the attack, why not scan everyone who attacks?  I did want them to stop, because all the log activity was bogging down my jbd2 process, and therefore all my disk access was slow.

Comment: If they've already compromised systems in your network it when it becomes a problem, it would tip them off and potentially make them cover their tracks or become more stealthy to avoid further detection.

The best way to stop a brute force is to block IPs when they fail a certain number of SSH logins.  You can also set the `MaxSessions` and `MaxStartups` options in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, which will limit the number of simultaneous connections and sessions, which will help prevent a slowdown.

Comment: @Craeft you seem to assume that these are all-in-one tools with everything built in. That's not necessary, and unlikely.